# best visual debugger for kernel

Tags: kernel, debugging

I have managed to get a user-mode-linux kernel compiled.  Now I can debug a kernel as a regular user process and track how it works.  This I can do using gdb but I'm much more used to visual debuggers and want to see and work with the code without needing to learn gdb commands.  Is there a good wrapper for gdb where I can control and see the code at the same time.  I don't need an ide since I am not really changing the code.  I have tried ddd but it is really slow and the interface is non-standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run gdb under emacs and it will track the source code in the other window.  You can also open watch windows and such.  It also has a bunch of other features that can make reviewing the code easier, such as tags tables which allow you to quickly jump directly to the definition of a given function, and the mark ring, which allows you to jump to one place, review the code a bit, then tap `C-x C-x` to jump back to where you came from.